# Binding dropdown value and object ID to function and setting state

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I have a manage users page where the users in the database are mapped dynamically into a table in rows. In each row we can select an account level to update the level of the specific user.

I have used binding, but don't know exactly how to carry it out. Below is the jsx file code.

```
                   <td>
                      <Form.Select className="accLevelForm"
                          name="accLevel"
                          aria-label="Default select example"
                          onClick={this.handleUserUpdate.bind(this, posts._id)}
                      >
                          <option>{posts.accLevel}</option>
                          <option value="1">Level 1 (user)</option>
                          <option value="2">Level 2 (admin)</option>
                      </Form.Select>
                  </td>
```

Here is the constructor

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state={
      posts:[],

      newAccLevel: 0
    };

    this.handleUserUpdate = this.handleUserUpdate.bind(this);
  }
```

How can I select the values from the dropdown and dynamically get the objectID of the specific user into the handleUserUpdate function and then push it to the backend? Or should I use a form submit button to do it seperately?

Here's the node part if you want to check it out

```
//update users
router.put('/updateUserLevel/:id', (req, res) => {
    const accl = Number(req.body.accLevel);

    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { accLevel: accl}, (err, docs) => {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
            res.json("Update unsuccessful")
        }
        else{
            res.json(docs)
        }
    } 
    
    )
})
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: set a state with `onClick` event on drop down options